# Bind sharepoint datas to The Kendo pivot grid by Kendo DLL or REST

Tags: iis, sharepoint, dll, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have many lists in sharepoint that gather information from other lists by lookup fields.

We have more that 30 reports that connect to lists and show data in *kendo grid*. But this [article](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/pivotgrid/overview) has complex things about kendo **pivot** grid.

We want to make a report by [kendo pivot grid](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/pivotgrid/overview).

First question is: I cant find this dll:  [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bmxXyl1UD0E&feature=youtu.be)

http://demos.telerik.com/olap/msmdpump.dll

And I don't know how I can host this dll in my **LOCAL** IIS or sharepoint. Further, I dont know the best way to use it safely. Here is a related [article](https://www.telerik.com/forums/securing-access-to-msmdpump-dll).

The next problem is that my datasource is not in SSAS - sql server and I have lists.

```
dataSource: {
                    type: "xmla", //define the type
                    columns: [{ name: "[Date].[Calendar]" }], //specify a dimesion on columns
                    rows: [{ name: "[Product].[Category]" }], //specify a dimesion on rows
                    measures: ["[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]"], //specify a measure to display
                    transport: {
                        connection: {
                            catalog: "Adventure Works DW 2008R2", //specify the name of the catalog
                            cube: "Adventure Works" //specify the name of the cube
                        },
```

In another try I can make synced sql server table in my DBs and I have tools that return json from sql but I can't make pivot simple sample by this component.

We have many javascript components like amcharts and Highcharts that use them and create many reports very easily in my SharePoint portal.

Is there any online sample that connected to SharePoint? One clear sample is better that 10 articles. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my way to use other [sample](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/pivotgrid/remote-flat-data-binding) in kendo pivot grid and use [this source](https://www.telerik.com/forums/northwind-svc-source-code) as a web service :

The given link is pointing to the service used in the demo, so you can examine its xml declaration directly here:
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/

You can also take a look at out service source code available here:
https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-demos-service/blob/master/KendoCRUDService/Northwind.svc.cs

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

1- in the server that installed SSAS you can find dll here: [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/instances/configure-http-access-to-analysis-services-on-iis-8-0) or [this](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radpivotgrid/how-to/howto-set-http-access-to-sqlserver)

2- install this features on your server

[image: CGI Application Development ISAPI Extensions]

Go to the download page for [SQL Server 2014 Feature Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=42295)

Click the red Download button.

Scroll down to find ENU\x64\SQL_AS_OLEDB.msi

Copy the following files, found at :\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\\OLAP\bin\isapi: MSMDPUMP.DLL, MSMDPUMP.INI, and a Resources folder.

[image: msmdpump.dll]

Create an application pool and virtual directory in IIS

Create App pool in iis

[image]

In IIS Manager, open Sites, open Default Web Site. You should see a folder named Olap. This is a reference to the OLAP folder you created under \inetpub\wwwroot.
OLAP folder before converted to an app
Right-click the folder and choose Convert to Application.

**Step 3: Configure IIS authentication and add the extension**

[image]

then you must grant execute to dll

[image]

**Step 4: Edit the MSMDPUMP.INI file to set the target server**

**Step 5: Grant data access permissions**

**Step 6: Test your configuration**

**Test connections using SQL Server Management Studio**

[image]

**Test connections using Excel**

On the Data tab in Excel, in Get External Data, click From Other Sources, and then choose From Analysis Services to start the Data Connection wizard.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<div id="example">
    <div id="configurator" class="hidden-on-narrow"></div>
    <div id="pivotgrid" class="hidden-on-narrow"></div>

    <div class="responsive-message"></div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var pivotgrid = $("#pivotgrid").kendoPivotGrid({
                filterable: true,
                sortable: true,
                columnWidth: 200,
                height: 580,
                dataSource: {
                    type: "xmla",
                    columns: [{ name: "[Date].[Calendar]", expand: true }, { name: "[Product].[Category]" } ],
                    rows: [{ name: "[Geography].[City]" }],
                    measures: ["[Measures].[Reseller Freight Cost]"],
                    transport: {
                        connection: {
                            catalog: "Adventure Works DW 2008R2",
                            cube: "Adventure Works"
                        },
                        read: "http://youserver/olap/msmdpump.dll"
                    },
                    schema: {
                        type: "xmla"
                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        alert("error: " + kendo.stringify(e.errors[0]));
                    }
                }
            }).data("kendoPivotGrid");

            $("#configurator").kendoPivotConfigurator({
                dataSource: pivotgrid.dataSource,
                filterable: true,
                sortable: true,
                height: 580
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        #pivotgrid {
            width: 70%;
        }

        .hidden-on-narrow {
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: top;
        }
    </style>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```